# What is wrong with my Tile creating and loading?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I've made a application that uses live tiles. I get it to work with the backgroundtask, it shows correct message but the image is completely black...

Here is my code where I save the image to `/Shared/ShellContent/`:

```
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            CurrentPlaceList = new ObservableCollection<CurrentPlaceListItemModel>();

            using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                    var bmp = new WriteableBitmap(173, 173);

                    var weatherImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images/WeatherIcons/01d.png", UriKind.Relative));

                    var img = new Image { Source = weatherImage };

                    weatherImage.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;

                    var tt = new TranslateTransform();
                    tt.X = 0;
                    tt.Y = 0;

                    bmp.Render(img, tt);

                    bmp.Invalidate();

                    var filename = "/Shared/ShellContent/01d.jpg";
                    using (var st = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, store))
                    {
                        bmp.SaveJpeg(st, 173, 173, 0, 100);
                    }
            }

            StartAgent();
        }
```

And where is my code where my ScheduledTask is supposed to update text and image, the images is completely black :(

```
        protected override void OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)
        {
            //TODO: Add code to perform your task in background
            UpdateAppTile("-99");

            NotifyComplete();
        }

        private void UpdateAppTile(string message)
        {
            ShellTile appTile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.FirstOrDefault();

            if (appTile != null)
            {
                StandardTileData tileData = new StandardTileData
                {
                    Title = message,
                    BackgroundImage = new System.Uri("isostore:/Shared/ShellContent/01d.jpg", System.UriKind.Absolute)
                };

                appTile.Update(tileData);
            }
        }
```

This is taken from several tutorials, could anyone put a finger on what is wrong?

Comment: Maybe you need to wait `ImageLoaded` event before render it to `bmp` or just copy image to `/Shared/ShellContent/` directory without creating additional `Image` objects. Also, you could look into `Isolated Storage` to see what is saved here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it looks like the image doesn't have enough time to load. I think the better way here is to do something like:

```
        StreamResourceInfo streamImage = Application.GetResourceStream(uri.Uri);
        BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
        bitmapImage.SetSource(streamImage.Stream);
        Image image = new Image() { Width = uri.Width, Height = uri.Height, Source = bitmapImage };
```

Also, you can check out a MSP Toolkit that could generate tile for you (msptoolkit on NuGet).